# How to remove duplicate elements from an XML file taking a parameter value into consideration

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT and facing a problem in getting an xml modified.

The input XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>

   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>top</brand>
      <color>black</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>B</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>brown</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>yello</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>C</label>
      <brand>middle</brand>
      <color>orange</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>B</label>
      <brand>top</brand>
      <color>blue</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>D</label>
      <brand>mid</brand>
      <color>green</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>mid</brand>
      <color>yello</color>
   </dictionary>

</xml>
```

It contains some of the  elements which has A as one of a child element. I want to remove the dictionary nodes containing duplicates. Also, while it removes the duplicates, it should only remove the duplicate nodes which also contain  != lower

The expected output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>

   <dictionary>
      <label>B</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>brown</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>yello</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>C</label>
      <brand>middle</brand>
      <color>orange</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>D</label>
      <brand>mid</brand>
      <color>green</color>
   </dictionary>

</xml>
```

On internet, I have found an xsl to remove the duplicate nodes based on an element value. The xsl to remove duplicate nodes is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="LABEL" match="dictionary" use="label"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dictionary[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('LABEL', label)[1]))]"  />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description "while it removes the duplicates, it should only remove the duplicate nodes which also contain != lower" is not clear to me, I have tried to implement it nevertheless with XSLT 2.0 as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="dictionary" group-by="label">
      <xsl:copy-of select="if (count(current-group()) eq 1)
                           then .
                           else current-group()[contains(brand, 'lower')]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>

   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>top</brand>
      <color>black</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>B</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>brown</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>yello</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>C</label>
      <brand>middle</brand>
      <color>orange</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>B</label>
      <brand>top</brand>
      <color>blue</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>D</label>
      <brand>mid</brand>
      <color>green</color>
   </dictionary>

   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>mid</brand>
      <color>yello</color>
   </dictionary>

</xml>
```

into the following result:

```
<xml>
   <dictionary>
      <label>A</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>yello</color>
   </dictionary>
   <dictionary>
      <label>B</label>
      <brand>lower</brand>
      <color>brown</color>
   </dictionary>
   <dictionary>
      <label>C</label>
      <brand>middle</brand>
      <color>orange</color>
   </dictionary>
   <dictionary>
      <label>D</label>
      <brand>mid</brand>
      <color>green</color>
   </dictionary>
</xml>
```

The stylesheet groups `dictionary` elements on the `label` child element value and the for each group outputs either the single element in the group if there is only one or it outputs those elements in the group where the `brand` child element value does contain `lower`.

As requested in a comment, I add an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) instead of `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="by-label" match="dictionary" use="label"/>

<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="dictionary[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-label', label)[1])]">
      <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('by-label', label)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($current-group) = 1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$current-group[brand = 'lower']"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks Martin. It actually meant brand!=lower, which I assumed you interpreted correctly and produced the required output. Can we write the same xsl login in xsl 1.0, since I am using 1.0 at all the places in my code. It would be really very helpful if I can get the same in xsl 1.0

Comment: I will edit and show a transcription of the XSLT 2.0 code to XSLT 1.0.